# How to match up variables between two arrays

Tags: arrays, merge

I have two arrays:

```
1. Array ( [0] => Class100 [1] => Class200 )
2. Array ( [0] => In Progress  [1] => Postponed )
```

I want to combine them in such a that the status matches the course. For example, the output should be something like:

```
Class100 = In Progress
Class200 = Postponed
```

I've tried merging the arrays hoping that it would do the trick, but the output is:

```
Array ( [0] => Class100 [1] => Class200 [2] => In Progress [3] => Postponed)
```

How can I get the desired results? I'm still pretty new at PHP, so please forgive me if this question to too simple for all the experts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem on this one. I used array_combine and it did the trick by turning the first array into the keys for the values in the second array.

Here's what I added:

```
$info = array_combine($classes, $status);

print_r($info);
```

The output was:

```
Array ( [Class100] => In Progress [Class200] => Postponed )
```

Thanks anyway to all of you who would've helped me out.